# Changing filter value by reading value from a cell in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a tab with slicers. One of the slicers filters the data by month. I'm trying to write code in VBA that uses a value in a cell on another tab to change the slicer filter. In this example, my slicer goes from 6 to 12. I want to enter 6 in Cell G3 on another tab, and then use that value in VBA to define which filter should be selected

This is the code :

```
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Quote_Month").VisibleSlicerItemsList = _
        Array( _
        "[Table_OpenSQ].[Quote Month].&[6]")
```

How do I change the "6" to whatever value is specified in a cell on another worksheet/tab?

Comment: Replace this `"[Table_OpenSQ].[Quote Month].&[6]"` with `"[Table_OpenSQ].[Quote Month].&[" & Worksheets("Name").Range("A1").Value &"]"` ... Change A1 as per cell in your sheet, and the name of the sheet

Comment: Great ... Accept the answer if it worked @Angie

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Quote_Month").VisibleSlicerItemsList = _
        Array("[Table_OpenSQ].[Quote Month].&[" & Worksheets("Name").Range("B1").Value & "]")
```